# Node creation PHP – menu item under proper parent

Tags: 7, routes

while I create node by PHP, I use this:

```
$node->menu['enabled'] = true;
$node->menu['link_title'] = $node->title;
```

but it puts link in 0 depth of the menu. It doesn't care for "Default parent" selected for content type. Neither this works:

```
$node->menu['parent'] = "menu-global-menu:961";
```

How to select parent then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to set `$node->menu['plid'] = "961";` to set the parent node.

You can have a look through the [menu_link_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) doco to get an idea of what is going on, or there is a [smaller code snippet on this blog](http://www.shealand.com/2010/09/23/add-menu-item-during-node_save-in-drupal-6) that explains in a simple, fast way.

As a side note, you can use `node_object_prepare($node);` to set default values after setting your node type, which should take care of your default menu parent. I've found [this guide](http://fooninja.net/2011/04/13/guide-to-programmatic-node-creation-in-drupal-7/) helpful with programmatic node creation.